# How to achieve beautiful user interface like website on windows form app?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-interface

I have done a lot work on windows forms, In the past user interfaces were not important, but this time it is important. I want to create a windows form app that has a great interface, like a beautiful website.

shown one example below
[image: example website]

Can I achieve this by any means in visual studio 2010? I don't have any experience of WPF, is it achievable there?

Comment: Yes you need WPF. winforms doesn't support customization.

Comment: You can do it both with WinForms and WPF, although it's 10 times easier with WPF. Other than that, it isn't really possible to answer this question

Comment: It's achievable in both WinForms and WPF but probably much easier in WPF.  In WinForms you would have to do a lot of custom drawing of controls or write controls from scratch for which you do all the painting.

Comment: @HighCore: I have no idea what you mean about WinForms not supporting customization.

Comment: @HighCore WinForms *does* support creating non-blocky UIs if that's what you mean. All .NET applications before Windows Vista had to use WinForms to create their UIs

Comment: @JohnSaunders sorry, my idea of certain technology or platform "ABC" *supporting* a certain feature "XYZ", is that you can **achieve** "XYZ" using "ABC" **without** having to resort to a bunch of idiotic hacks. Does COBOL support creating Web applications? Yes, of course, it's doable, however, would you recommend anyone to start a Web project in COBOL, today, in 2015? winforms is exactly the same as COBOL, totally irrelevant, useless and deprecated.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `All .NET applications before Windows Vista had to use WinForms` - and that's why they all sucked. BTW that was 6+ years ago.

Comment: @HighCore, again? Why you hate `Winforms`?

Comment: @Fabio I don't *hate* anything. I simply gave an advice to the OP, and stated a FACT that winforms doesn't support customization. There's no hate in that.

Comment: Ok, but `Winforms` do support customization until some level, after this level was reached, you need to make more work then for example in `WPF` to achive what you need

Comment: @Fabio sorry, my idea of `customization` is [this](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/), not being able to put a lame background image in your form. The amount of support that winforms has for such a thing is `zero`. Yours might be different, though.

Comment: @HighCore Multimedia applications, even touch enabled multimedia applications aren't a new thing in Windows. As for customizing your form background or creating non-rectangular forms, just search SO among others. We could even create forms with holes in them long before WPF

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and yet you needed to resort to a bunch of "owner draw" hacks. Yes you can do the same in COBOL, too. See my comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this and much more in WPF (consider nice animations when you mouse-over or click items, or when tab changes, etc). Do not even try winforms, there are paid libraries, which can provide you with components to create rich user interface, but winforms is not flexible in any way by itself. In wpf you can achieve EXACTLY look you want.

Specifically to screenshot:

- On top is some `ItemsControl` with items (`DataTemplate`) what has restyled checkbox (or vector graphics) and background bound to current item.
- Below is `ContentControl`, which takes data template for current item (`UserControl`).
- Actual content is simple restyled standard controls, it's very easy to make them looks like this.

Comment: i've seen even asp.net control are not that good looking ,they needed a lot of customization so html control and javascript is used what about wpf controls? If WPF controls are good looking just like html and css then there is nothing left ,i'll add code in the event's

Comment: Default appearance of controls is rather close to winforms one. To be able to customize their appearance you have to learn wpf. Get a book or two, read through quickly to get idea about everything, then practice individually each part: styling, templating, animations, etc. If you have winform experience, then you can start straight, because many concepts are still: events, [custom controls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27783407/1997232), etc. But to be able to achieve *nice look* you need to have some practice and perhaps designer talents.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms is a *legacy* technology and does not provide you good tools to create your good looking custom controls. You need to work with low level API's to draw your controls like **GDI+**. If you are eager to learn, it is not that hard. It is indeed fun to work with GDI+ drawing shapes and painting them etc, but it will cost you a lot of time and it probably won't look too good.

Other than that if you want to stick with Windows Forms but develop your UI quickly, you can use [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx) libraries but they cost a lot of money.

As Sinatr said, the most common way is to go with **WPF**. You will access powerful tools like **Blend** and a modern API to create and customize your set of controls. You can still utilize DevExpress and Telerik control in WPF.

Comment: It's Blend, not Blender. Blender is a 3D animation software not related to WPF in any way.